# Why is the call_history.db empty on iOS 8.0?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I've got a jail broken iOS 8.0 device and in the Phone app I can see there is a call history and I've just made a few calls from/to the device it ensure there should be call history entries. 
However when I try and access `/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db` there are no rows retrieved from the database.

So where is the device getting the call history from if its not from here? AFAIK the change from CallHistory/call_history.db being the location to CallHistoryDB/CallHistory.storedata occurred in iOS 8.3, but I'm running 8.0.

Here is the code, its getting SQLITE_DONE instead of SQLITE_ROW.

```
  NSString *callHisoryDatabasePath = @"/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db";
    BOOL callHistoryFileExist = FALSE;
    callHistoryFileExist = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:callHisoryDatabasePath];
    NSMutableArray *callHistory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if(callHistoryFileExist) {
        if ([fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:callHisoryDatabasePath]) {
            sqlite3 *database;
            if(sqlite3_open([callHisoryDatabasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
                sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
                NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithString:@"SELECT * FROM call;"];



            int errorCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1,
                                               &compiledStatement, NULL);
            if( errorCode == SQLITE_OK) {
                int count = 1;
                int result = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
                while(result == SQLITE_ROW) {**** here result is SQLITE_DONE*****
                ...
```

Comment: Why do you assume scheme of the database is the same? They've changed it. Download iFile from Cydia and you can browse file system and open SQLite databases. Much easier to research that way. Or copy it to your PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change from `call_history.db` (wireless domain) to `CallHistory.storedata` (home domain) was made on **iOS 8.0**, so you're looking at the wrong database.

`CallHistory.storedata` is SQLite too, even if it's a CoreData DB.
Obviously, tables and fields are completely different.

Comment: Is there anything extra needed to do to access CallHistory.storedata? A call to NSFileManager:fileExistsAtPath supplying "/private/var/mobile/Library/CallHistoryDB/CallHistory.storedata" returns false. Do I need to add any entitlements to the project for example to access the new location/file?

Comment: Hey Sausage,Even I am getting false when I am checking for /var/mobile/Library/CallHistoryDB/CallHistory.storedata

But true when I am checking /var/mobile/Library/CallHistoryDB

Did you get the solution for getting call histroy ?